# _NSZombie_NSKeyValueUndefinedGetter - What is this?

Tags: ios, nszombie

Hey everyone,
I'm getting a senseless error when I load an application I'm writing for the first time.

> Class _NSZombie_NSKeyValueUndefinedGetter is implemented in both ?? and ??. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Anyone's had this issue before? It happens only when NSZombies are enabled.
Thanks in advance to everyone.

Comment: I'm getting this message as well, I was hoping for an answer.  It's really flaky, it shows sometimes, and sometimes it doesn't.  It doesn't seem to be affecting anything though, i.e. the app is not crashing and I'm not getting any EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with troubleshooting EXC_BAD_ACCESS and had hard time to find the setting with Xcode 4.2 (the latest one that comes with iOS5 SDK). Apple keeps on moving things and the settings are no longer where they used to be.

Fortunately, I've found it and it works for the device, not just Simulator. You need to open the Product menu in the Xcode, select Edit scheme and then choose the Diagnostics tab. There you have "Enable Zombie Objects". Once selected and run in debugger will point you to the double released object! Enjoy!